# Android - inserting into database after finishing AsyncTask

Tags: android, database, class, android-asynctask

I am pretty much new in Java (& android), hence I can't solve it with my limited knowledge despite searching extensively.

In the code below, I want to get a JASONArray from a weblink through AsyncTask. After that I want to populate my database from the array data.

To do that I created the RemoteConnectivity class where I can populate an ArrayList importdata with all the data from JASONArray. But the problem is, I cannot access my database class mylibmandbhandler from inside RemoteConnectivity class (I guess because that is not extended to Activity). And in ImportExport class, if I write the code to insert into database just after calling RemoteConnectivity().execute() [as in code below], it starts inserting before execution ends (very obvious because it is property of AsyncTask).

Now, can anybody please guide me through this? Or any link please to understand the whole process (I am lost in at least 50 pages I read about it :( ).

P.S. mylibmandbhandler is a Class I created (not activity) in my package src folder for my database operations.

```
public class ImportExport extends Activity {
    public void webimport(View v){
        new RemoteConnectivity().execute(); // START OF ASYNCTASK

        //INSERT importdata INTO DATABASE AFTER EXECUTE
        mylibmandbhandler db = new mylibmandbhandler(this);
        for (String[] s : importdata){
        db.addRecord(new mylibman(s));
        }
    }

    final ArrayList<String[]> importdata = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    private class RemoteConnectivity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
    {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ..................
        ..................
        importdata.add(dataline); // POPULATE ARRAYLIST IMPORTDATA

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result1) 
    {
        // WHAT TO WRITE HERE
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should insert the data in the `onPostExecute` as follows:

```
public class ImportExport extends Activity {
    public void webimport(View v){
        new RemoteConnectivity().execute(); // START OF ASYNCTASK        
    }

    final ArrayList<String[]> importdata = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    private class RemoteConnectivity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            ..................
            ..................
            importdata.add(dataline); // POPULATE ARRAYLIST IMPORTDATA

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result1)
        {
            //INSERT importdata INTO DATABASE AFTER EXECUTE FINISH (POST EXECUTE)
            mylibmandbhandler db = new mylibmandbhandler(ImportExport.this);
            for (String[] s : importdata){
                db.addRecord(new mylibman(s));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The reason is because, onPostExecute is the method (callback) which is executed after the data has been done downloading in the `doInBackground` method.

**Alternatively**: You can also put the `insert` statements inside the `doInBackground` if you want the inserting to be done by background thread. This may be helpful, if inserting into the database is time consuming. In such a case the UI thread won't block. '

```
public class ImportExport extends Activity {
    public void webimport(View v){
        new RemoteConnectivity().execute(); // START OF ASYNCTASK        
    }

    final ArrayList<String[]> importdata = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    private class RemoteConnectivity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            ..................
            ..................
            importdata.add(dataline); // POPULATE ARRAYLIST IMPORTDATA

            //INSERT importdata INTO DATABASE. NOW DONE IN THE BACKGROUND THREAD (Alternate method)
            mylibmandbhandler db = new mylibmandbhandler(ImportExport.this);
            for (String[] s : importdata){
                db.addRecord(new mylibman(s));
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result1)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Update**: The important this to highlight in my answer is that I used `new mylibmandbhandler(ImportExport.this);` instead of `new mylibmandbhandler(this);` as `this` refers to `AsyncTask` which is not what the constructor supports.

Comment: the problem is mylibmandbhandler is giving error "The constructor mylibmandbhandler(ImportExport.RemoteConnectivity) is undefined", if I put inside onPostExecute method

Comment: `new mylibmandbhandler(ImportExport.this);` is the key I think.

Comment: oh sorry, missed that .. lemme try

Answer (score 1):

You need to use method onPostExecute to insert data to datatable. Like this:

```
private class RemoteConnectivity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ..................
        ..................
        importdata.add(dataline); // POPULATE ARRAYLIST IMPORTDATA

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result1)
    {
        //INSERT importdata INTO DATABASE AFTER EXECUTE FINISH (POST EXECUTE)
        mylibmandbhandler db = new mylibmandbhandler(ImportExport.this);
        for (String[] s : importdata){
            db.addRecord(new mylibman(s));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well, ofcourse I did that at first .. but the problem is mylibmandbhandler is giving error "The constructor mylibmandbhandler(ImportExport.RemoteConnectivity) is undefined"

Comment: @AbdullahFahim See edited answer. Thats because 'this' refers to AsyncTask object at that position. You need to specify it as 'ImportExport.this'.